# Categorical crossentropy?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I’m trying to classify a dataset that contains review text and an overall rating.

I pre-processed the data and converted the labels (1-6), into a binary classifier and use an embedding layer input algorithm with a dense layer output. The dataset is balanced so equal number of each review overall rating.

My algorithm is not too bad. It gave me a 85% , 84% accuracy and validation accuracy. When I don’t convert it into a binary classifier it does much worse (40% ish) which isn’t as bad as merely guessing.

My question is why does it perform much lower? Is it that because the difference in text sentiment between 4 and 5 isn’t as obvious as the difference between 2 and 5, or is it because when I combined it into a binary classifier, there are consequently more rows for each label?

I really want to develop a categorical text classifier and not just classifier whether the review is below or above 3. Is an accuracy of 40% good given guessing is 20%?

Thanks

Comment: Did you use an activation function in your output dense layer. If yes, what activation function?

Comment: I used sigmoid for both @vbhargav875

Comment: @Jay Why did you used sigmoid in case of multiclass classification ? Sigmoid is good for doing binary classification. You should use softmax activation in the output layer while doing multiclass classification.

Comment: But I converted the label to a binary array, for example 1 -> [0,1,0,0,0], 5-> [0,0,0,0,5]

Comment: @Jay That type of conversion doesn't make sense. For each rating, you can keep their one-hot encoding:
1 -> [0,1,0,0,0,0] and 2-> [0,0,1,0,0,0] ... 5-> [0,0,0,0,0,1]

Comment: Sorry it was a typo error. Anyway in one hot encoding, why is softmax better than sigmoid? Their functions looks similar?

Comment: @Jay Sigmoid gives transforms the input value to [-1, 1] range and this is good enough to do binary classification because more the value is towards 1 then more chances for it to be positive sample but in case of multiclass classification, you need probabilities for each class so the output for each class should follow properties of probabilities that is all the individual class probabilities should be positive and they should add to 1.